# Drupal 7 Image Styles saving thumbnails in the large styles folder

Tags: image, drupal, image-processing, drupal-7

I'm not sure if anyone else has had this problem or not but here goes.

I've set up my local environment with the following modules
Image Crop
ImageMagick
Colorbox

All other image modules are in core i.e. imagefield, imagecache etc.

The problem i'm having is in when I save an image in my content type, after uploading and cropping, I'll go to the page click on an image and it will only show the thumbnail in the colorbox, I've made all the correct setting available in field display in my content type to show the large image style in the colorbox but will always only show the thumbnail, when I checked whether the large image was saved in its directory i found that it was only saving the thumb there as well.

Does anyone have any insight into what my issue is?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because you're using the Image Crop module, you want to be referencing the original image in display settings for the full colorbox.

Make sure the image settings "The resolution to crop the image onto" are the correct dimensions as well.